# Handle Concurrency Java level vs database/JPA level

Tags: multithreading, jpa-2.0, java.util.concurrent, optimistic-locking, optimistic-concurrency

**Scenario**: In any kind of online Reservation application there is possiblty that people may acesses the application at the same time. 
Because of this there could be a concurrency issues in that perticular application.

**Problem**:

In this case, if one or more people  accessing the application at a time then there is a problem of concurrency issue.

To solve concurrency the issue we have two solutions

1) Java Concurrency at Client level

2) JPA Optimistc or Pessimistic Locking at persistence level

If the database contains 10 millions or more records then which one is the optimal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance issues and Concurrency issues are two different problem domains altogether. Its better not to mix both.

**Regarding concurrency issues:**
*Java Concurrency or Multi threading* may be of very limited use in a online reservation system. To avoid problem of [lost updates](https://crackingjavainterviews.blogspot.com/2018/04/how-will-you-block-two-concurrent-web.html), you must use either JPA Optimistic Locking (preferably) or Pessimistic Locking. That's because if multiple instances of your application are running in parallel (or multiple threads) then its impossible to avoid lost updates using JVM level thread-safety techniques.

You can refer to the below tutorials:

1. [JPA Optimistic Locking - Oracle Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/locking-and-concurrency-in-java-persistence-20)
2. [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjjf.html)

Comment: which solution is optimal?JPA Optimistic Locking (preferably) optimal to implement or do we get deadlocks from database

Comment: if we use Java Concurrency  we do not get deadlocks timeout from database

Comment: In Optimistic Locking, we have to retry the failed transactions (OptimisticLockException) ourself, dead locks should not occur. Java Concurrency is not a solution to database level conflicts, so thats out of scope for this discussion.

Comment: if you have 10 millions or more records in your database then also JPA Optimistic Locking optimal solution?

Comment: It will depend on thread contention (number of threads writing to a single shared variable), rather than number of total records. If thread contention is high, performance will degrade irrespective the number of records in database table.

Comment: I am still doubtful to apply locking at persistence level. If the Datasets are large normally we receive timeouts and deadlocks from database.So again if we apply locking ,it means adding extra burden to database.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the application. If the Datamodel, not complex and not huge then the JPA Optimistic Locking is an optimal solution.

Both Java & Database Concurrency have there own advantages and disadvantages.

**Database level:**

**Advantage:**

1) its easier to implement and also for maintenance.

**Disadvantage:**

1)If the database contains huge and complex data then it may causes deadlocks and timeouts.

---

**Java Level:**

**Advantages:**

1) Better resource Utilization

**Disadvantages:**

1) Debugging & Testing very complex.

2) There is a possibility deadlock occurence.

3) Difficult to implement in Java Programming.

4) An Element of risk involved with a bad design.(Starvation)

5) it's not portable from one environment to another environment

ref: [java Concurrency vs JPA concurrency](https://crackingjavainterviews.blogspot.com/2018/04/how-will-you-block-two-concurrent-web.html)

ref: [database vs user level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809643/database-or-user-level-locks?rq=1)